# How to implement `range()`

Tags: java, language-features, range

### Intro

How to write public static **range method** or **Range class**, in Java 6, so that it would at least cover common functionality implemented in other programming languages?

If you want to answer the question, then you can just ignore following.

---

### About

Time after time I miss functionality, that other languages have. I happen to have different coding style for about any language I write and I'm not willing to change that habit. So, if I want to reuse an algorithm, that I have written in a different language, then I have to make annoying little hacks or workarounds, to cover missing functionality. I'd like to find permanent and efficient fix for `range()`.

For me - `range()` method returns range of input, possibly in a lazy manner and it has default values. At any point it has a start, a condition of ending and a way to get the next element. It should work perfectly in **for each** loop as well as outside it.

### Notes

I would really prefer not to use a any external library, except Google Guava or equivalent. By equivalent I mean code that is properly tested, works excellently with JDK and is not considered deprecated.

[image]

It might be unclear, so:

- by `How to write` I mean - you do not have to write it, just describe common pitfalls and what are the pros and cons of the recommended approach.
- this is `loop code`, but can also be used
- this is not a homework :P

Aside from integer input, that would be the most used feature, I would really like it to work well with type instances of classes like BigInteger and Joda DateTime.

### Ideas

- must be able to use in `for-each` loop
- generic, but typesafe
- ables using pre-existing container methods, like: .cycle(), .filter(), .all(), .any(), transform()

As a method, `range()` header could look like:

```
/**TODO: Think about why / how to add step, limit, offset and cycle detection. */
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Iterable<T> //
range(T from, Predicate<T> to, Function<T, T> fNext) //
        throws NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException {
```

As a personal preference, I have written `Range` as Builder pattern implementation.

### Edit

Range implementations [**Scala**](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.7/scala/Range.html), [**Python 3**](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html?highlight=range#range), [**Groovy**](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Range.html), [**.Net** (with linq) [c#, f#, vb and c++]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx), [**ruby**](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html), [**PHP**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) ... And all of them differ.

I might as well add an example of from what I want to do better ( [simple sample case](http://pastebin.com/wPmMbU1F) ).

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Iterable<T> //
range(T from, Predicate<T> to, Function<T, T> fNext) //
        throws NullPointerException {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(from);
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(to);
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(fNext);

    T current = from;
    ArrayList<T> result = Lists.newArrayList();
    if (to.apply(current)) result.add(current);
    while (to.apply(current = Preconditions.checkNotNull(fNext.apply(current))))
        result.add(current);
    return result;
}
```

or lazy alternative

```
//eats first element
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Iterator<T> //
range2(final T from, final Predicate<T> to, final Function<T, T> fNext)
        throws NullPointerException, UnsupportedOperationException {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(from);
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(to);
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(fNext);
    return new Iterator<T>() {
        T current = from;
        @Override public boolean hasNext() {return to.apply(current);}
        @Override public T next() {return current = Preconditions.checkNotNull(fNext.apply(current));}
        @Override public void remove() {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
    };
}
```

Comment: It's prolly not what you want, but its close...http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3792

Comment: Despite your description, I find I'm making assumptions about what you want in your `range`.  It may be helpful if you could point out a specific language and/or point to the documentation of a `range` keyword/class/method/API of another language/library that you are trying to emulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pain point will probably be having to write the functions for each type:

```
  public static Function<Integer, Integer> intIncrementer(final int step) {
    class IntIncrementer implements Function<Integer, Integer> {
      private final int _step = step;

      @Override public Integer apply(Integer i) {
        return i + _step;
      }

      @Override public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (obj instanceof IntIncrementer) 
           && ((IntIncrementer) obj)._step == _step;
      }

      @Override public int hashCode() {
        return _step;
      }
    }

    return new IntIncrementer();
  }
```

Since there is no way to express `i + _step` in a generic fashion, you would have to reimplement this for every type you wanted to support (`BigInteger`, `long`, etc.)

I would question the need to use `<T extends Comparable<T>>` instead of just `<T>`. I see no advantage in imposing this restriction.

Unlike the collections, the [Iterable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) type imposes no [equality contract](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29). It might be better to return a `Range` type that defined such a contract if you wanted to be able to compare ranges without externally iterating over all their elements.

```
public interface Range<T> extends Iterable<T> {
  // TODO: write the terms of the contract
  @Override public boolean equals(Object obj);
  @Override public int hashCode();
  // TODO: other useful methods?
}
```

When it comes to the primitives, there is going to be overhead in creating wrapper objects. This may be significantly less efficient over large ranges compared to just using a traditional incrementing `for` loop.

Comment: I could not think of any data structure, that should not have `compareTo` method and be subject of `range`. Also I fail to understand why I must impose equality contract at the first place. And the `pain point` is ensuring code works as it should, not writing the code. Besides, I could store defaults map or enum of `i + _step`, but it is quite common to change that part anyways so I do not see the problem. Java does not have a generic primitives option and I thought, I mentioned by saying I want to use BigInteger, that I do not care about that.

Answer (score 0):

I would just take the closest path. Create an interface such as this:

```
interface Steppable<T>{
    T defaultStep(); //Returns 1 for most number types
    T value(); //Returns the value itself
    Steppable<T> step(T amount); //the stepping logic
}
```

Write a whole bunch of implementations of the interface for every type I want to use inside the range function (ints, longs, dates, etc.). Then create an overloaded `range()` function for each steppable type for ease of use.

I would go for this approach because it makes adding more steppable types fairly straight-forward. As for the disadvantage, the approach is somewhat verbose.